# ERROR: Project#afterEvaluate(Closure) on project ':app' cannot be executed in the current context

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Hi can anyone help me to resolve "ERROR: Project#afterEvaluate(Closure) on project ':app' cannot be executed in the current context." in android studio

Comment: are u using one signal in your project? whats your gradle version?